# What is the estimated age of Naruto when he became Hokage?

Tags: naruto

On the last chapter of the manga version, Naruto became the Hokage. How old is he when he became Hokage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ### `/!\` Spoiler Warning
>
> This answer contains spoilers from the end of the manga. Read it at your own risk.

This is just an educated guess, based on information from various point in Naruto's series timeline.

From [Naruto's biography](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki):

- In Naruto first season, his age is about 12-13
- In Naruto Shippuden, his age is about 15-17

We also know that he has two children, and his eldest son Bolt (Boruto) is currently a student in the Ninja Academy.

Additional information:

- In Bolt's current character design, Bolt's physical appearance ranges from 10 to 12 years old, probably the same age as his father when Naruto was studying at the Ninja Academy.
- Let's assume 13 is the average age of the students when they graduate from Ninja Academy.
- There is a 2 year time skip in the *The Last: Naruto the Movie*.
- Let's give 1-3 years margin of error for Naruto and Hinata to have bonded.
- Naruto's current age in Shippuden is about 17.
- Kakashi just stepped down from his position as Hokage. Since he was about 31 in Shippuden, and he became the 6th Hokage after the two year time skip, so he is about 33 at that time.

Solution would be:

```
a = 10,11,12 = +-2
b = 13
c = 2
d = 1,2,3 = +-2
e = 17

Naruto_Age = a + b + c + d + e
Naruto_Age = (+-2) + 13 + 2 + (+-2) + 17

Minima Naruto's Age = 28
Maxima Naruto's Age = 36
```

Getting the average of minima and maxima, as the two margins of error (which come from Bolt's current age and the time needed for Naruto and Hinata to get together) are pretty much assumed.

**Naruto's age when he became Hokage is estimated to be 32.**

Comment: This would be the most logical age estimation so far. But let's see what the others have to say.

Comment: Your calculation is a bit weird. For Bolt's age, if you assume him to be 10 to 12, then you should add 11 (+- 1) to the age. And the time for him to get together with Hinata should be 2 (+- 1) if you want to give them 1 to 3 years. Like that, Naruto's age would be 17 + 2 + 2 (+-1) + 11 (+-1) = 32 (+- 2). Also, I don't get how Kakashi has anything to do with the calculation (and also Naruto's age in the first season).

Comment: Naruto's age has to do something with being in the ninja academy for time basis, while Kakashi's age is the assumed average age for most of the Hokages. This is just my own speculation. You could have made an answer based on my answer in your own discretion.

Comment: @MikeAnte: I don't read the series, but just that I find the way you present the calculation a bit weird, so I want to try to understand your intention when you include those information and edit to clarify your post. One thing I still don't understand: why did you use 13 for the age of Bolt, while you say that his age is around 10 to 12 from his character design? It seems that Bolt is still at the academy at the end of Naruto.

Comment: 10 to 13 is the basis average age for the students who graduate at the student academy and 13 at most (assumed). Bolt is used as a reference to add into the current age of Naruto when he had his first child. It is assumed that he started dating Hinata at around 17 to 19 and I gave them a grace period of 3 years for them to copulate. Hope this helps.

Comment: That wrong 17+ 10= 27 he been twenty seven at the end of it all