# How old was Hinata when she had her children?

Tags: naruto

How old were Naruto and Hinata when they had Bolt and later Himawari?

I have just been puzzled by the question and couldn't come to an answer.

Comment: related http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/what-is-the-estimated-age-of-naruto-when-he-became-hokage

Answer (score 8):

Chapter 700 of the manga takes place **15 years** after the 4th SWW. During the 4th SWW, Naruto is 17 and Hinata is 16.

So at present, they're 32 and 31 respectively.

Boruto's age is revealed to be 12. There's a confirmed two year age difference between Himawari and Boruto. Therefore Hima is 10 years old.

Since Hinata is 31 years old currently. Therefore, she was 19 when she had Boruto and 21 when she had Himawari.

Answer (score 3):

They would be in their 30's with Naruto at 31-32 and Hinata at 29-30.

At the end of the war, they were 17 and 16. Skip two years to the last movie and they are 19-20 and 18-19. Twelve more years where Boruto is 12, that would make them 32 for Naruto and 30 for Hinata.