# How old is Naruto throughout the show's timeline?

Tags: naruto

I am curious about Naruto's aging through the series from Naruto to the beginning of Naruto Shippuden. From what I've gathered Naruto's birthday is in October.

Under the assumption that he was 12 at the start of the series. I think it went something like the following :

- Age 13 during the Chunin Exams
- Age 14 when Sasuke left the leaf
- Age 16 when came back from training with Jiraya

Can someone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: Naruto's birthday was mentioned to be the 10th of October

Answer (score 2):

From the [Naruto wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki) (Part II as in Shippuden):

```
Age   Part I: 12-13  
      Part II: 15-17
```

So by the end of the manga/anime, he's 17 before the larger timeskip.

Also, there was a good answer by Mike Ante on another [related question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/what-is-the-estimated-age-of-naruto-when-he-became-hokage).

Comment: I believe he 'celebrates' his 17th birthday during the 4th Shinobi War (not sure if it was 17 but he definitely had his birthday while fighting Obito since it was specifically mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Not correct, the time skip was 3 years long so naruto was 13 at the end of naruto, cause during the pain arc Minato asks him how old he is and he answers 16 and during the war arc at the end when he says goodbye to his dad and the other kage, it's actually his birthday and he turned 17.

Comment: Can you include sources to support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

he is 11-12-13 during the 
the first part of naruto after two years time skip he was 15 and then during the five kage summit he was 16 than war arc he turned 17 and then in the last movie of naruto he was 18 or 19 years old

Answer (score 0):

In the Boruto manga/anime he is around 32 to 35 years old. If he had Boruto at the age of 21 like most people would agree with, he would be 33 or 34 years old. He became hokage at the age of 24 and Boruto remembered that day as shown in one of the episodes. But, in the original Naruto anime he was 12 or 13 the entire show cause it never showed any sign of a time skip. So it obviously went through in a few months inside of the show. After the time skip when he arrived back with Jiraiya, he was 15 but turned 16 shortly as shown when he met his dad. He turns 17 in the Fourth Great Ninja War. In The Last, Naruto was 18 and turned 19 in a few days in this movie yet there was another time skip. Hinata was pregnant with Boruto, so Naruto was 20 or 21.